# Laravel collection fetch empty array but sql gives proper results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, mysql-workbench

I want to fetch some result from database and the raw sql query give proper outputs when run in phpmyadmin but laravel give empty array.

```
    $transectionDetails=Wallet_transaction::query();

    $transectionDetails->select('kitchen_name','parent_id',DB::raw("CONCAT(f_name, ' ', l_name) AS name"),'transaction_amount','transaction_time','transaction_id')
    ->join('parent_details','wallet_transactions.parent_id', '=','parent_details.id')
    ->join('kitchens','parent_details.kitchen_id', '=','kitchens.id')
    ->whereNotNull('wallet_transactions.transaction_id')
    ->where('wallet_transactions.transaction_for',2);

    if(!empty($post_data) && $post_data['parent_name'] != ''){
        $transectionDetails->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(f_name, ' ', l_name)"), 'like', "'%".$post_data['parent_name'] ."%'");
        // echo '<pre>';var_dump(get_class_methods($transectionDetails));
        echo '<pre>';var_dump($transectionDetails->toSql());
        echo '<pre>';var_dump($transectionDetails->get());die;

    }
```

`var_dump($transectionDetails->get());die;`

this give empty array but database give proper array.

`var_dump($transectionDetails->toSql());` 
gives:

```
  select `kitchen_name`, `parent_id`, CONCAT(f_name, ' ', l_name) AS name,
  `transaction_amount`, `transaction_time`, `transaction_id` from 
  `wallet_transactions` inner join `parent_details` on 
  `wallet_transactions`.`parent_id` = `parent_details`.`id` inner join 
  `kitchens` on `parent_details`.`kitchen_id` = `kitchens`.`id` where 
   `wallet_transactions`.`transaction_id` is not null and 
   `wallet_transactions`.`transaction_for` = ? and CONCAT(f_name, ' ', 
    l_name) like ?
```

what is wrong in it???**

Comment: The second one is giving you the query, not the result, check what you have done wrong in your query so that it doesn't return any result.

Comment: Try `$transectionDetails = $transectionDetails->get()` or `$transectionDetails = $transectionDetails->select(...)`  then do `var_dump`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$transectionDetails = Wallet_transaction::query();

$transectionDetails = $transectionDetails->select('kitchen_name','parent_id',DB::raw("CONCAT(f_name, ' ', l_name) AS name"),'transaction_amount','transaction_time','transaction_id')
    ->join('parent_details','wallet_transactions.parent_id', '=','parent_details.id')
    ->join('kitchens','parent_details.kitchen_id', '=','kitchens.id')
    ->whereNotNull('wallet_transactions.transaction_id')
    ->where('wallet_transactions.transaction_for',2);

if(!empty($post_data) && $post_data['parent_name'] != '') {
        $transectionDetails = $transectionDetails->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(f_name, ' ', l_name)"), 'like', "'%".$post_data['parent_name'] ."%'");
        $results = $transectionDetails->get();
        dd($results);
}
```

You need to keep your query variable updated with the modifications you are applying to it.

*I hope it helps*

Comment: ok .Thank you .where(DB::raw("CONCAT(f_name, ' ', l_name)"), 'like', "'%".$post_data['parent_name'] ."%'");
        $results = $transectionDetails->get(); I change it to WhereRaw, Now it works.

Comment: @Arunima perfect, please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you resolve the issue so that we can close this thread on stack overflow